# Run functions using Soot

Tags: soot

I am trying to use soot to measure execution time for every function in a particular class. I have tried to read all tutorials of Soot Framework by Eric Bodden.

What I have come up till now is this,

```
package test;

import java.util.Map;

import soot.Body;
import soot.BodyTransformer;
import soot.PackManager;
import soot.Scene;
import soot.SootClass;
import soot.SootMethod;
import soot.Transform;

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PackManager
                .v()
                .getPack("jtp")
                .add(new Transform("jtp.GotoInstrumenter", GotoInstrumenter.v()));

        System.out.println(Scene.v().defaultClassPath());
        SootClass sootClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("test.TestClass");


        if (sootClass == null || !(sootClass instanceof SootClass)) {
            System.out.println("sootClass not initialized");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println(sootClass.getMethodCount());
        }
        sootClass.setApplicationClass();
        for (SootMethod m : sootClass.getMethods()) {

            try {
                new Transform("jtp.GotoInstrumenter", GotoInstrumenter.v())
                        .apply(m.retrieveActiveBody());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exeception in for loop : " + e);
            }
        }

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("all")
class GotoInstrumenter extends BodyTransformer {
    private static GotoInstrumenter instance = new GotoInstrumenter();

    private GotoInstrumenter() {
    }

    public static GotoInstrumenter v() {
        return instance;
    }

    protected void internalTransform(Body body, String phaseName, Map options) {

        System.out.println("Processing method : "
                + body.getMethod().getSignature());
    }
}
```

and here is my TestClass

```
package test;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I am in test class");
    }
    public void f1(){
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 10));
    }
}
```

I have added sootclasses by using add variable in eclipse and executing it like a Java Application.

This is my program output:

```
C:\Users\Aks\Java\soot-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Aks\workspace\SootAnalysis\bin;D:\Installs\eclipse\plugins\ca.mcgill.sable.soot.lib_2.5.2\lib\sootclasses.jar;;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
3
Processing method : <test.TestClass: void <init>()>
Processing method : <test.TestClass: void main(java.lang.String[])>
Processing method : <test.TestClass: void f1()>
```

Now I understand that Soot has read the bytecode and is stepping through all the methods. What i want to do is, run each of them. Is this possible using the Soot Framework??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is not why people want to use soot. I don't know if there is any elegant way to do that using soot. But, definitely, you can utilize the power of reflection here. Adding the following line at the end of *internalTransform()* method should work:

`TestClass.class.getMethod(body.getMethod().getName()).invoke(new TestClass());`

Of course, there is nothing like *init()* method within the class *TestClass*. So, you don't want to invoke that method. Also, for *main()* method, you need to specify the correct parameter as per the syntax of reflection. Otherwise, there will be exceptions.

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: This is really nothing that Soot supports (or even should support). Hence using Reflection or just using a shell script seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Mainul. Very later did I realize Soot only does static analysis. Sorry, my bad